# PHP: Making a property private to a trait

Tags: php

I just discovered that private properties in traits are not private to the trait, they are private to the class that uses the trait.

This means that if you have two traits that define the same private property, you'll get a warning message:

```
trait DataOne {
  private $_data;
}

trait DataTwo {
  private $_data;
}

class SomeClass {
  use DataOne;
  use DataTwo;
}
```

PHP gives you the following warning message:

```
DataOne and DataTwo define the same property ($_data) in the 
composition of SomeClass. This might be incompatible, to improve 
maintainability consider using accessor methods in traits 
instead. Class was composed in SomeClass.
```

I have a library with several traits, and renaming every private property to be distinct isn't practical. What mechanism can I use to define a property or variable that is visible to all methods within to a trait, yet invisible to the class that uses the trait?

Comment: Traits are basically just copy and paste in PHP. Maybe you should look into using abstract classes where private means only accessible to that class. It'll be a lot of refactoring but it's the only way to achieve your goal.

Comment: The whole point of traits is to segregate functionality into small chunks and add them to only the classes that need them.

Comment: You're not wrong, but that doesn't change the fact that the language doesn't support combining two or more traits that have overlapping property names - conflict resolution is only available for methods, not properties. I think you could make a decent case that having properties in traits is fundamentally a bad idea, and that they should only really be used for sharing functionality, not state. Ultimately, the only way you're going to get round this is by either giving your traits unique property names, or more thoroughly refactoring your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see a trait as a class, it isn't.

Actually, a trait is just a piece of code that you glue on the class where you use it, so it don't respect methods and properties visibility.

Maybe you need to rethink about your class structure to fit you needs.

Comment: I find a lot of people abuse traits and overlook OOP fundamentals.

Comment: A lot of people don't understand OOP basics. Unfortunately.

Comment: This is commentary, not a solution.

Comment: There's no solution for this problem, but instead of commenting, I'm explaining him how traits work.